# JavaPoet + Android Studio "addModifiers(Modifier) cannot be applied to Modifier"

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, javapoet

I've built an annotation processor for my Android project that builds a source file using JavaPoet. However, every time I need to call `addModifiers` on any JavaPoet object, Android Studio flags it as an error. It will say either

```
Cannot resolve method addModifiers(javax.lang.model.element.Modifier)
```

or

```
addModifiers(javax.lang.model.element.Modifier) cannot be applied to javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
```

depending on which object I'm calling the method on. I've checked many times that the two fully qualified class names match perfectly. These methods in JavaPoet use VarArgs arguments, but that shouldn't make a difference since I'm compiling to Java 7.

Now here's the kicker: The package compiles just fine, and creates my source file. It only gives me the error in the IDE, not when javac runs. The modifiers are correct in the generated file.

So I guess what I want answered is: How do I get rid of the IDE error, and who do I report this to? Is this a JavaPoet issue, an Android Studio issue, or an IntelliJ issue, or something I haven't considered yet?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you found a solution?

Comment: look at my answer can work

Answer (score 0):

this question is like  To this one 
[How to get a reference to Modifier.PUBLIC that can not be applied in builder in MethodSpec's methodBuilder for JavaPoet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957630/how-to-get-a-reference-to-modifier-public-that-can-not-be-applied-in-builder-in/59047175#59047175)

You just only add this code to your build.gralde

```
implementation 'org.checkerframework:checker:2.1.10'
```

that error will gone.the error is that   andorid studio  bugs,

### this error is same to belows

you can reference belows

first :https://github.com/square/javapoet/issues/632
[image]

#### error gone by add this

[image]

Comment: This does work because the checkerframework contains all of the `javax.lang.model` directly in the jar. Note this could potentially cause problems with inconsistent versions, so use with care.