# How to get a reference to Modifier.PUBLIC that can not be applied in builder in MethodSpec's methodBuilder for JavaPoet

Tags: android, javapoet

Attempting to implement the basic JavaPoet example (see below) in a Android ActivityWatcher class from LeakCanary:

```
.addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.STATIC)
```

The Modifier.PUBLIC and Modifier.STATIC, and the other .addModifiers statement  produce the Android Studio error

> addModifiers (javax.lang.model.element.modifier...) in Builder can not be applied to (int, int)

and the following gradle error:

```
:Machine-android:compileDebugJava
```

C:\AAAMachine\Machine-master\Machine-android\src\main\java\com\bmp\ActivityWatcher.java:58: error: cannot access Modifier
              .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.STATIC)
              ^
  class file for javax.lang.model.element.Modifier not found
C:\AAAMachine\Machine-master\Machine-android\src\main\java\com\bmp\ActivityWatcher.java:65: error: method addModifiers in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
              .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.FINAL)
              ^
  required: Modifier[]
  found: int,int
  reason: varargs mismatch; int cannot be converted to Modifier
C:\AAAMachine\Machine-master\Machine-android\src\main\java\com\bmp\ActivityWatcher.java:73: error: cannot access Filer
          javaFile.writeTo(System.out);
                  ^
  class file for javax.annotation.processing.Filer not found
C:\AAAMachine\Machine-master\Machine-android\src\main\java\com\bmp\ActivityWatcher.java:172: error: method addModifiers in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
              .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.STATIC)
              ^
  required: Modifier[]
  found: int,int
  reason: varargs mismatch; int cannot be converted to Modifier
C:\AAAMachine\Machine-master\Machine-android\src\main\java\com\bmp\ActivityWatcher.java:179: error: method addModifiers in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
              .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.FINAL)
              ^
  required: Modifier[]
  found: int,int
  reason: varargs mismatch; int cannot be converted to Modifier
C:\AAAMachine\Machine-master\Machine-android\src\main\java\com\bmp\ActivityWatcher.java:187: error: cannot access Path
          javaFile.writeTo(System.out);
                  ^
  class file for java.nio.file.Path not found
Note: C:\AAAMachine\Machine-master\Machine-android\src\main\java\com\bmp\internal\MachineInternals.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
6 errors

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':Machine-android:compileDebugJava'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.881 secs

and here's the error from messages:

```
:machine-android:compileDebugJava
```

C:\AAAmachine\machine-master\machine-android\src\main\java\com\bmp\ActivityWatcher.java
Error:(58, 15) error: cannot access Modifier
class file for javax.lang.model.element.Modifier not found
Error:(65, 15) error: method addModifiers in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
required: Modifier[]
found: int,int
reason: varargs mismatch; int cannot be converted to Modifier
Error:(73, 19) error: cannot access Filer
class file for javax.annotation.processing.Filer not found
Error:(172, 15) error: method addModifiers in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
required: Modifier[]
found: int,int
reason: varargs mismatch; int cannot be converted to Modifier
Error:(179, 15) error: method addModifiers in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
required: Modifier[]
found: int,int
reason: varargs mismatch; int cannot be converted to Modifier
Error:(187, 19) error: cannot access Path
class file for java.nio.file.Path not found
Note: C:\AAAmachine\machine-master\machine-android\src\main\java\com\bmp\internal\machineInternals.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
Error:Execution failed for task ':machine-android:compileDebugJava'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 6.881 secs
>   Information:7 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Here's the gist of the source code using the basic example from the readme.md file from JavaPoet:

```
package com.bmp;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.bmp.util.eventbus.FabricLogEvent;
import com.squareup.javapoet.JavaFile;
import com.squareup.javapoet.MethodSpec;
import com.squareup.javapoet.TypeSpec;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

import de.greenrobot.event.EventBus;

import static android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
import static android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH;
import static com.bmp.Preconditions.checkNotNull;



@TargetApi(ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) public final class ActivityWatcher {

    public static void installOnIcsPlus(Application application, RefWatcher refWatcher) {
        if (SDK_INT < ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
          // If you need to support Android < ICS, override onDestroy() in your base activity.
          return;
        }

    ActivityWatcher activityWatcher = new ActivityWatcher(application, refWatcher);
    activityWatcher.watchActivities();

    MethodSpec main = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("main")
            .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.STATIC)
            .returns(void.class)
            .addParameter(String[].class, "args")
            .addStatement("$T.out.println($S)", System.class, "Hello, JavaPoet!")
            .build();

    TypeSpec helloWorld = TypeSpec.classBuilder("HelloWorld")
            .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.FINAL)
            .addMethod(main)
            .build();

    JavaFile javaFile = JavaFile.builder("com.bmp.helloworld", helloWorld)
            .build();

    try {
        javaFile.writeTo(System.out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("com.bmp.newclass.java"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Could it be related to the physical file name to be written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your imports to `import javax.lang.model.element.Modifier`. If you can’t import this package change your project’s module configuration from the Android SDK to the Java SDK.

Comment: Is there a way to compile this as a module within a Android project in Android Studio or is there a aar file I could use?

Answer (score 0):

In your Android project, create a single Java module for code use JavaPoet.
suce as [image: select the java library]

In this module, your `build.gradle` file should be like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.7.0'
}
```

[image: the build.gradle in the java library].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your answer. When you want to show a code snippet, it's best to show it as text. Then users can copy-paste it. To put code in `code markdown`, indent it by 4 spaces. Thank you for contributing, I hope your answer will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

### **I find this way  can work**

this just is Android studio bug . Android studio code check error for that .
add this code in your build.gradle in your moudle ,or your app module ,that error will go gone!

```
implementation 'org.checkerframework:checker:2.1.10'
```

add this one ,and the processor module will work

The whole build.gralde like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.11.1'
    implementation 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc6'
    implementation 'org.checkerframework:checker:2.1.10'

    api project(':baseAnnotation')
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```

#### the important is

```
implementation 'org.checkerframework:checker:2.1.10'
```

### this is caputure of my android studio show

[image]

remember only add this  to your build.grale (app or  moudle  both work for you )
this  error just  code check error ,just android studio app  check error

```
   implementation 'org.checkerframework:checker:2.1.10'
    provided project(':processAnnotation')
    annotationProcessor project(":processAnnotation")
```

processAnnotation is my process Module .